# ArcGIS Pro time slider display

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, time-series

I have time-enabled data in ArcGIS Pro. The time field is strictly YYYY-MM-DD, but the time slider shows YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.

Is there a way to configure the time slider display to strictly show YYYY-MM-DD?

The HH:MM:SS values really aren't meaningful in my data.

Comment: I think the short answer is no. I've found no options to alter the display of the time slider.